# Calculating the apparent molecule length from density of the bulk

Tags: molecular-structure

I'm interested to estimate the *apparent* length of the water molecule *assuming* it could be approximated as a cube.  This is an intentional simplification.

### Calculating molecule length from volume in density equation

I used this equation to find the volume for a mole of water molecules with $\varrho$ (water density, assumed $\pu{0.997 g cm^{-3}}$), $m$ (mass), and $V$ (volume).

For the determination of the molar volume, I substituted mass $m$ by molar mass $M$ and rearranged

$$\varrho = m / V$$

into the equivalent form

$$V_{\mbox{molar}} = \frac{M} {\varrho} = \frac {\pu{18.01 g mol^{-1}}} {\pu{0.997 g cm^{-3}}} = \pu{18.06 cm^3 mol^{-1}}$$

Because $\pu{1 m^3} = \pu{10^6 cm^3}$, the molar volume equates to $\pu{18.06 \times 10^{-6} m^3 mol^{-1}}$.

Given Avogadro's number, I computed the volume of the individual  volume with

$$V_{\mbox{molecule}} = \frac{ \pu{18.06 \times 10^{-6} m^3 mol^{-1}}} { \pu{6.022 \times 10^{23} mol^{-1}} } = \pu{2.999 \times 10^{-29} m^3}$$

Then I took the cube root to find the length, as I want $m^3 \rightarrow m$:

$$\ell(\text{molecule}) = \sqrt[3]{\pu{2.999 \times 10^{-29} m^3}} = \pu{3.10 \times 10^{-10} m} = \pu{0.31 nm}.$$

##### What I need help with

This isn't taking intermolecular forces into account, but I want to know if it's an ok method for getting a rough idea of the molecule length, and if it's done correctly.

Comment: Density often is denoted by $\rho$ (`$\rho$`) or $\varrho$ (`$\varrho$` in LaTeX / [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/) syntax available to you here on chemistry.se), which is different to $p$ then *typically* used about pressure.  But this is smallish compared to the initial equation, because density *is not* mass times volume, but mass *divided* by volume (e.g., water, 1 g per cubic centimetre, or about a [metric] ton per cubic metre.  The length you obtain is about twice as wide as the (intramolecular) H-H distance (about 0.15 nm).

Comment: Assuming molecules as small cubes is a simplification and it depends a lot on the circumstances if this is acceptable, or not. It may be a start of a model later to be refined (e.g. limiting the number of interactions modelling crystal growth) for water's bent, or benzene's flat shape. For future reference: if you use an equality sign, then both numbers and dimensions must equate, too. This shows  e.g., when they cancel out ([dimension analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis#The_factor-label_method_for_converting_units)) even if this demands a bit more to type / write.

Comment: Over time (and repeated exposure) you will pick up skills new to you.  Once you have enough reputation, for example, you may e.g. access to the edits made by other users.  This equally is a source of inspiration (and eventually, training) by reference for how to format questions and answers in the community of chemistry.se (maybe you know the expression of «when in Rome, do as the Romans do»).

Comment: Strange this question was closed for the reason given but from things you have said @buttonwood my question is answered (about if it can be used roughly to estimate length), would gladly have given you the answer if your stuff wasn’t in a comment.

Comment: For me, I struggled to relate your statements of «calculating the total bond energy» and «intermolecular forces» on one hand, with the target the question addresses, the determination of a length of a molecule, on the other.  The later just (implicitly) assumes inflexible molecules, like stacking dies next to / on top of each other. If the molecules come closer to each other (e.g., compression, external pressure, lower temperature [with exceptions like solid water]), then bulk density simultaneously will increase.

Comment: That was just a bit of extraneous info I took it out. I think calculating molecule length in this way assumes highest possible density, I ignored intermolecular forces (affects density) as hydrogen bonding can lead to a decrease in density, but as you rightly pointed out, the shape also matters which is being ignored as well, guess I should’ve specified STP

Comment: It actually is fascinating how close you get with this absolutely simplistic approach. I#m not sure why this was closed, I wouldn't have. But I'm also not confident enough to overrule this decision. Also (but not entirely sure how helpful this is): https://www.researchgate.net/post/Molecular-volume-of-8-water-molecules-by-DFT-and-connolly-surface-method

Comment: Ah you’re right it’s 0.27nm… since water is in a tetrahedron shape, can you convert cubic units to tetrahedral units? I don’t know if that’s even a thing my maths is weak @Martin